# Sharing string arraylist values between different sessions

Tags: java

I have a situation where 2 users or more want to use multiple locations (to unload goods) but I need to make sure that only one of them is unloading at one location and the others are waiting until he finishes (if they have orders to unload at the same location).

I was thinking of storing the location name in an arraylist `occupiedLocations` and use a check if the location is occupied or not before the user can enter the location and then remove the location name when he finishes, but the problem is the values inside the arraylist is not shared among different sessions.
I know it's possible to store the values in a database, but is there another option that doesn't require writing/reading from a database.

Comment: What sessions ?

Comment: You could load the data from the database into a cache.  Storing to the DB isn't so bad, and ultimately the data will end up there anyway.  Use appropriate indices for faster read times.

Comment: I'd use a set rather than a list and some global object with synchronizing mechanisms. What "global" means depends on your environment, e.g. if CDI is available it might be an application scoped bean.

Comment: Different user sessions.

Comment: What assylias probably means is: are you talking about http sessions, jpa sessions, custom session objects etc.? That means you might have to provide more details about your application/environment to help us make a suggestion.

Comment: I really don't know, I'm kind new to programming, but what I know is that we use a custom software that determines the location and show it on an RF terminal.

Comment: @MMahrous As Thomas points out, the answer really depends on the technology - don't you know what technology you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best aproach will be to use database with read/write lock to prevent simultaneous reads even running in a clustered environment.

But this is the proffesional solution. If you plan to do a small application with no clustered execution the ServletContext or even a Static attribute containing this data will be enough. Be sure to make `sychronized` the methods that write/read this data.

A very simple example:

```
public static class MyApplicationSharedData {
private static ArrayList<String> locations = new ArrayList();

private static synchronized void writeLocation(String location) {
  locations.add(location);
}

public static void waitForLocation(String location) {
  while (locations.contains(location)) {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);// sleep for a second while the location is bussy
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      log.error(e);
    }
  }
  writeLocation(location);
}

public static synchronized void freeLocation(String location) {
  locations.remove(location);
}
```

}

Usage sample:

```
MyApplicationSharedData.waitForLocation("Denver");
// Do stuff
MyApplicationSharedData.freeLocation("Denver");
```

Comment: It worked when I put them all in a separate class, Thanks.

Comment: Remember to be careful with deadlocks. This is a very simple example